# How to add new field based on sum of previous documents that comes before every document in Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, typescript, database, mongodb, mongoose

When a collection is sorted by date, I am trying to add a new field to every document based on values of previous documents that comes before the document. Context is that I am trying to create a line graph out of entries so I need the current sum for every entry.

Example is like this:

```
Input:
Collection:

Document-1: { type: 'typeX', date: '01-01-2000', value: 10 }
Document-2: { type: 'typeY', date: '01-03-2000', value: -5 }
Document-3: { type: 'typeX', date: '01-02-2000', value: 3 }
Document-4: { type: 'typeX', date: '01-03-2000', value: -1 }
Document-5: { type: 'typeY', date: '01-01-2000', value: 10 }

Output:
{ type: 'typeX', date: '01-01-2000', value: 10, sum: 10}
{ type: 'typeY', date: '01-01-2000', value: 10, sum: 10}
{ type: 'typeX', date: '01-02-2000', value: 3, sum: 13}
{ type: 'typeY', date: '01-03-2000', value: -5, sum: 5}
{ type: 'typeX', date: '01-03-2000', value: -1, sum: 12}
```

IS this possible with `aggregate` or any other way in Mongoose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use [$setWindowFields](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setWindowFields/) because it:

> Performs operations on a specified span of documents in a collection, known as a window, and returns the results based on the chosen
> window operator. For example, you can use the
> `$setWindowFields` stage to output the Difference in sales between two documents in a collection...Cumulative sales totals...

Use this aggregation which will work with mongoose `Model.aggregate()` too:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $setWindowFields: {
      partitionBy: "$type",
      sortBy: {
        date: 1
      },
      output: {
        sum: {
          $sum: "$value",
          window: {
            documents: [
              "unbounded",
              "current"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      date: 1
    }
  }
]);
```

See [HERE](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JPrHHmovTZt) for a working example.

Comment: This works great, thanks so much!!

Comment: You're welcome. There are quite a few options with `$setWindowFields` and works with a host of accumulation operators so comes in very handy.